# Compare one column (A) against another archival column (B), when found, return the text in the same row in column C

Tags: excel, text

I think my question is relatively simple:

Here is the deal. I have one column (A) that contains text. I have an archival column (B). Column C the text that I really want for each instance of whatever appears in B.  So, I need to compare column A with B and whenever A is identical to B, I need Excel to return the text that's in column C immediately in that row.

I have no idea how to do this. Can someone please help?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try entering this formula.

```
=IF(A1=B1,C1,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative interpretation of the question:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A1,B:B,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out!!!!

Here is what I did and it worked!
=VLOOKUP(A2:A3207,$B$2:$C$5106,2,FALSE)

It compares all values in A (I had 3207 different texts) to column B, and then returns what ever is in column C of which I had 5106 different values.

took a while!
Thanks y'all